# How to check date should not be past date for current date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery datepicker.i have to validate that selected date should not be past date from current date like given below

from 2015-06-12
to 2015-05-12

how to validate this ...

Comment: What have you tryed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use: `Date.parse(date) > Date.now()` for comparison to now,
or `Date.parse(comparableDate1) > Date.parse(comparableDate2)` for general comparison

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8ppv0py/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a fiddle example for doing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/H3H8s/5/

**Script :**

```
if(dateCheck("02/05/2013","02/09/2013","02/07/2013"))
    alert("Availed");
else
    alert("Not Availed");

function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var fDate,lDate,cDate;
    fDate = Date.parse(from);
    lDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(check);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using JS Datepicker, you can restrict the min-date to current date.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adityamantha/vt763wsb/)

```
$(function(){
var d = new Date();
$('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate:"-1d",
    maxDate:"d"
});
```